# Anyone know of a custom GPS ROM for Samsung Galaxy 5?

Tags: gps, custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I recently bought a Samsung Galaxy 5 (model number GT-I5500) and I'm new to the android world.

I'm not satisfied with the performance of the GPS on my cell phone so I thought it would be interesting to use a custom ROM to see if it improves a bit.

Anyone knows of a ROM that was tested in this model?

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily what you are looking for, but on my Captivate, the GPS is kinda slow. I just came across [this](http://admin.androidcentral.com/quick-fix-gps-issues-your-new-samsung-galaxy-s-series-phone) and thought I'd try it later tonight.